# System.MissingMethodException: Method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.GetValueOrDefault' not found

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, exception, xamarin.droid

I'm working on **Xamarin.droid** application which was running fine till yesterday. But suddenly when I try to run the code I'm getting the **exception on runtime** once the project started to run on device

> System.MissingMethodException: Method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.GetValueOrDefault' not found.

I removed all the code changes and let it be in the previous working state.
 Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
 Removed bin and obj folders.
 Linker property is already set to "None".
 Removed unnecessary packages. 
Restarted Visual studio. Restarted the system. But still no use.
 Using ***Visual studio enterprise 15.5.7.***

Any help is appreciated...

**Edited:**
It got resolved in my case.
I run the app from VS, it throws the exception. Then I opened the app settings and cleared cache/data. Then opened the app. It worked as expected. Then run the app from VS. Then also it worked without throwing the exception. But don't know what exactly went wrong previously.

Comment: Run your code in the debugger. It will tell you where the issue is.

Comment: You mean in debug mode? That is how I was trying.

Comment: Yes, it will stop at the position where the exception occurs, so look what happens there. If you can’t find anything look at the exception’s call stack trace for more information. If you still can’t find the cause, copy the full call stack trace and append it to your question, so we have more details.

Comment: The problem is that this exception occurs inside the NuGet package. So the debugger not stopping anywhere in my program and also there is this one line alone in the exception stacktrace. The same code was running previously. Even though there is no code changes, it is not working now.

Comment: You said that you removed unnecessary packages... Have you tried removing necessary packages and reinstalling them using nuget?

Comment: No @cy-c. Just now it got resolved. But don't know what exactly went wrong. I run the application. It throws the exception. Then I went to app settings and cleared cache/data. Then I opened the app it worked as expected. Then I run the application again from VS. It worked without exception!

Comment: @Developer, did you get the root cause of this issue by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time that I have seen this exception using Xamarin, it was something related to Linker configuration and compiler optimizations.

Comment: Can you tell me any configurations that I need to change?

Comment: Go to project properties -> Android options ( dont remember exact title) -> linker. Set that to none to see if it works.
you can also check this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Comment: The problem is that "GetValueOrDefault" method is begin removed from your code as output optimization. Which Xamarin Android version you are using? Is GetValueOrDefault implemented in that version?